# Total array of object based on another array value

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create new array of object with total data by year(or any selected key) but, it doesn't work as expected.

```js
const dataArray = [
  {
    "abc": 10,
    "xyz": 20,
    "year": "2021"
  },
  {
    "abc": 20,
    "xyz": 20,
    "year": "2022"
  },
  {
    "abc": 20,
    "xyz": 10,
    "year": "2021"
  },
  {
    "abc": 30,
    "xyz": 10,
    "year": "2022"
  },
  {
    "abc": 20,
    "xyz": 10,
    "year": "2021"
  },
  {
    "abc": 10,
    "xyz": 10,
    "year": "2022"
  }
]
const keys = ["year", "abc", "xyz"];
const cols = ["year"]

//expected
//[{ "abc": total of abc for 2021, "xyz": total of xyz for 2021, "year" "2021"}, { "abc": total of abc for 2022, "xyz": total of xyz for 2022, "year" "2022"}]

const newObject = {};
cols.forEach(col => {
 dataArray.forEach(arr => {
  keys.forEach(key => {
    if(col != key) {
      newObject[key] += col[key]
    }
  })
 })
})

console.log(newObject);
```

I tried above but doesn't work as expected.

My expectation is:

```
[
  {
    "abc": "total of abc for 2021",
    "xyz": "total of xyz for 2021",
    "year": "2021"
  },
  {
    "abc": "total of abc for 2022",
    "xyz": "total of xyz for 2022",
    "year": "2022"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const dataArray = [
  {
    "abc": 10,
    "xyz": 20,
    "year": "2021"
  },
  {
    "abc": 20,
    "xyz": 20,
    "year": "2022"
  },
  {
    "abc": 20,
    "xyz": 10,
    "year": "2021"
  },
  {
    "abc": 30,
    "xyz": 10,
    "year": "2022"
  },
  {
    "abc": 20,
    "xyz": 10,
    "year": "2021"
  },
  {
    "abc": 10,
    "xyz": 10,
    "year": "2022"
  }
]

const result = dataArray.reduce((res, ele) => {
  let exist = res.find(e => e.year === ele.year)
  if(exist) {
    exist.abc += ele.abc
    exist.xyz += ele.xyz
  } else {
    res = [...res, {...ele}]
  }
  return res
}, [])

// other way
const result1 = Object.values(
  dataArray.reduce((res, {year, ...rest}) => {
    let ele = res[year] ??= {year}
    Object.entries(rest).forEach(([k, v]) => ele[k] = (ele[k] ?? 0)  + v)
    return res
  }, {})
)
console.log(result, result1)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can aggregate `dataArray` using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), building an object whose keys are the `year` values and values are the accumulated `abc` and `xyz` values. You can then convert that into your desired array format using [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values):

```js
const dataArray = [{
    "abc": 10, "xyz": 20, "year": "2021"
  },
  {
    "abc": 20, "xyz": 20, "year": "2022"
  },
  {
    "abc": 20, "xyz": 10, "year": "2021"
  },
  {
    "abc": 30, "xyz": 10, "year": "2022"
  },
  {
    "abc": 20, "xyz": 10, "year": "2021"
  },
  {
    "abc": 10, "xyz": 10, "year": "2022"
  }
]

const keys = ["year", "abc", "xyz"];
const cols = ["year"]

newObject = Object.values(
  dataArray.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    colkey = cols.map(k => obj[k]).join('##')
    if (acc.hasOwnProperty(colkey)) {
      keys.filter(k => !cols.includes(k)).forEach(k => acc[colkey][k] += obj[k])
    } else {
      acc[colkey] = obj
    }
    return acc
  }, {})
);

console.log(newObject);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important }
```

Comment: But, I don't know it's `year` or `month`. It should be based on `cols` array. So, I should iterate over `cols` before `reduce`?

Comment: Because if I do that it's not working:

`newObject = Object.values(
  cols.forEach(col => {
      dataArray.reduce((acc, { col, ...rest }) => {
      console.log(col);
    return acc
    });
  }, {})
)`

Comment: @ketan it wasn't really clear from your question what you wanted, so I wrote an answer based on the data in the question. I think I understand better now, and I've updated my answer to group based on the `cols` array and sum the values based on the keys in the `keys` array that are not also in the `cols` array. Please see my edit...

Answer (score 0):

if you want some different approach

```
  const dataArray = [
  {
    "abc": 10,
    "xyz": 20,
    "year": "2021"
  },
  {
    "abc": 20,
    "xyz": 20,
    "year": "2022"
  },
  {
    "abc": 20,
    "xyz": 10,
    "year": "2021"
  },
  {
    "abc": 30,
    "xyz": 10,
    "year": "2022"
  },
  {
    "abc": 20,
    "xyz": 10,
    "year": "2021"
  },
  {
    "abc": 10,
    "xyz": 10,
    "year": "2022"
  }
]
let mainObj = {}
dataArray.forEach((el)=>{
    if(!mainObj.hasOwnProperty(el.year)){
        mainObj[el.year] = {}
        mainObj[el.year].abc = el.abc
        mainObj[el.year].xyz = el.xyz
        mainObj[el.year].year = el.year
    }
    else{
        mainObj[el.year].abc = mainObj[el.year].abc + el.abc
        mainObj[el.year].xyz = mainObj[el.year].xyz + el.xyz
        
    }
})
let values = Object.values(mainObj)
console.log(values)
```